# Ruby on Rails: How to customise error message for MailForm when field is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, message, mail-form

At the moment, if I leave a field in the form blank, I get an error message that is written in the en.yml file, how can I overwrite this error message in the model?

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message,   :validate => true
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true
```

This is what I've tried for the name attribute but I'm still getting the error message which is written in the en.yml file. I can't change the error message from en.yml as it is for another part of my application.

```
  validates :name, presence: { message: "Can't be blank" }
```

Any ideas why this is not overwriting the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the error message using `i18n` localization in the same way that you would for a regular `ActiveRecord` model. The only difference is that you use the `mail_form` top-level scope instead of `active_record`.

```
# en.yml
mail_form:
   errors:
      models:
         contact:
            attributes:
               name: 
                  blank: "My custom message goes here"
```

sources:

- [MailForm i18n Documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form#i18n)
- [Translations for ActiveRecord Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

Comment: where can i get the full list of keywords? e.g. for "email already taken" what should i put in place of `blank` field.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nest the message in an inner hash. The syntax for messages on validations is:

```
attribute :name, validate: true
```

Not very elegant, but you can set the error message manually:

```
contact = Contact.new
contact.valid?  # => false
contact.errors[:name] = "Can't be blank"  # => Will add "Can't be blank to the list of errors associated with  name"
```

Or, if you want to replace the original error:

```
contact.errors.set(:name, "Can't be blank")
```

Comment: This just gave me an error: Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'

Comment: You're right, I thought you were extending `ActiveRecord::Base`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This had no effect

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers are not working (try them out first, rails is good with error messages) you could use JQuery to validate the fields before submit, there is a plugin for that https://jqueryvalidation.org/

From there site

```
    $("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // some other code
    // maybe disabling submit button
    // then:
    $(form).submit();
  }
 });
```